# numeric/string to only numeric

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, how transform a "numeric/string" variable to only numeric? Using some function or regular expression.?

Sample:
Input: 11.489.301/0001-47
to: 11489301000147

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove any non-numeric characters, and [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert the string type to a number type:

```
var num = Number("11.489.301/0001-47".replace(/\D/g, ""));

alert(num);
//-> 11489301000147
```

Comment: +1! what is the difference between Number(str) and parseInt(str)? ty :)

Comment: @steweb: in this instance, not much.  `parseInt` will search for a valid number at the beginning of any string, for instance `123abc` would yield 123.  On the other hand, if the number looks like an octal and the `radix` argument isn't passed to `parseInt`, it will be parsed as an octal number, e.g. `010` would yield `8`.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to just remove everything that is not digits from a string you can use a regular expression:

```
s = s.replace(/\D+/g,'');
```

If you then want to turn the string it into a numeric value, you can parse it:

```
var n = parseInt(s,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for this:
"11.489.301/0001-47".replace(/\D/g,"")

Comment: `"\D"` is not a regular expression literal, it's a string, so the code will only replace the first occurance of the character `D`.

Comment: That's right, my bad. I've corrected the answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp)/[parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) global functions. 
They will strip any leading characters and return only the numeric representation.